# Appending form value to GET/POST Requests in Go

Tags: go

I would like to define a `http.Client` that automatically appends a form value to all GET/POST requests.

I naively tried implementing `http.RoundTripper` as copy/pasted from another library uses this technique to modify headers for every request.

```
type Transport struct {
    // Transport is the HTTP transport to use when making requests.
    // It will default to http.DefaultTransport if nil.
    // (It should never be an oauth.Transport.)
    Transport http.RoundTripper
}

// Client returns an *http.Client that makes OAuth-authenticated requests.
func (t *Transport) Client() *http.Client {
    return &http.Client{Transport: t}
}

func (t *Transport) transport() http.RoundTripper {
    if t.Transport != nil {
        return t.Transport
    }
    return http.DefaultTransport
}

func (t *Transport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // To set the Authorization header, we must make a copy of the Request
    // so that we don't modify the Request we were given.
    // This is required by the specification of http.RoundTripper.
    req = cloneRequest(req)
 >> req.Form.Set("foo", bar)

    // Make the HTTP request.
    return t.transport().RoundTrip(req)
}

// cloneRequest returns a clone of the provided *http.Request.
// The clone is a shallow copy of the struct and its Header map.
func cloneRequest(r *http.Request) *http.Request {
    // shallow copy of the struct
    r2 := new(http.Request)
    *r2 = *r
    // deep copy of the Header
    r2.Header = make(http.Header)
    for k, s := range r.Header {
        r2.Header[k] = s
    }
    return r2
}
```

This however does not work. The `req.Form` values map doesn't seem to exist at this stage, so I get the panic:
`panic: runtime error: assignment to entry in nil map`

I tried adding this to the `(t *Transport) RoundTrip`, but no luck:

```
err := req.ParseForm()
misc.PanicIf(err)
```

I've no idea what I'm doing, any tips?

EDIT: There is no point in trying to copy `req.Form` values in `cloneRequest` method, since `r.Form` is empty map anyway.

Comment: Do you want to add a request parameter, or modify a form body?

Comment: @JimB I would like to add the request parameter to every request.

Comment: but what do you intend to do when there's a `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Do you still want to append a parameter to the url?

Comment: In those cases, I'd like to raise an error (as a future reminder). Right now, I don't have such use cases (I think).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Form`, `PostForm`, and `ParseForm()` are only used when receiving a request. When sending a request, the Transport expects the data to be properly encoded.

You have the right idea by wrapping `RoundTrip`, but you have to handle the encoded data yourself.

```
if req.URL.RawQuery == "" {
    req.URL.RawQuery = "foo=bar"
} else {
    req.URL.RawQuery = req.URL.RawQuery + "&" + "foo=bar"
}
```

or alternatively:

```
form, _ = url.ParseQuery(req.URL.RawQuery)
form.Add("boo", "far")
req.URL.RawQuery = form.Encode()
```

You could also choose to check the `url.Values` beforehand, if you want to avoid duplicating keys. Checking the `Content-Type` header for `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to avoid interaction with other types of queries may be a good idea too.

Comment: Works like a charm. I handled `content-type` as well.