# How to add values to request and redirect in golang

Tags: http, go, request, microservices

I have API gateway and User service micro services. When a request comes to API gateway, I need to add some values before `Rediret()` it to user service.

```
func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/login", userLogin)

}
func userLogin(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    uuid := generateUUID()

    // How to add UID to request?
    http.Redirect(res, req, userservice, http.StatusSeeOther)

}
```

For that I have used method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301051/appending-form-value-to-get-post-requests-in-go).

```
form,_ := url.ParseQuery(req.URL.RawQuery)
form.Add("uid", "far")
req.URL.RawQuery = form.Encode()
```

This just go and stop at User Service's login route.

I also tried to use : `req.Form.Set("uid","foo")`

This gives a panic.

> http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:55076: assignment to entry in nil map

My User service :

```
func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/login", UserLogin)
}

func UserLogin(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
     req.ParseForm()
     requestID := req.FormValue("uid")
     userID := req.FormValue("userid")

     if userID =="sachith"{
        sendRequest(requestID)
        http.Redirect(res, req, "http://localhost:7070/home", http.StatusSeeOther)
    }
```

Is there a way to add values to request we receive for a route and the redirect it to another service?

Comment: Have you tried adding the query params to the `url` parameter of the `Redirect` method? (properly formatted with `?` and `&` of course). E.g. `http.Redirect(w, r, userservice + "?uid=far", http.StatusSeeOther)`.

Comment: Adding these query parameters to req does not what you seem to expect it to do. http.Redirect redirects to the url you supply as the 3. arguemnt and you probably want to add the query parameters there.

Comment: Note that the solution in the linked post is for *client* requests, what you're dealing with here is a *server* request which, once received, should seldom, if ever, be modified by a non-middleware handler.

Comment: @mkopriva Nope, doest work. Service stops at `userservice:7071/login?foo=bar`

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram help us help you.

Comment: @mkopriva Sorry about that. I just wanted to understand where I got stuck. I have updated question. Hope it will help.
So should I update my user service to handle `/login/{uid}` ?

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram I don't know how `/login/{uid}` is supposed to help you. If your simple redirect with query parameters, as suggested in previous comment, doesn't work for you then doing `/login/{uid}` can't possibly solve the actual problem. Redirecting, with or without query params, is very simple, see for example this gist: https://gist.github.com/mkopriva/199932d3320f2de07028a86f95a5a1e1 it works on my local machine, if you can't run this example in your environment then your environment is broken. The Go net/http.Redirect works as advertised in the documentation.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks, this solved my previous two issues too. Can you please post gist as an answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add query parameters to a redirect location you simply add them to the `url` argument of the [`Redirect`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Redirect) function.

Also, you should not modify the `*http.Request` argument that's passed in to `Redirect` to specify the target location, that's not what it's for. 1st, modifying  it would only have an effect on relative redirects, which is not what you're trying to do here. 2nd, the `url` is designated for that purpose and can be used consistently to do both relative and absolute redirects. There's no advantage going against the design here.

`apigateway/main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/login", loginHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    uuid := "911cf95b-6b3f-43fd-b695-c80c79145c51" // generate uuid
    http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:8081/login?user_id="+uuid, http.StatusSeeOther)
}
```

`userservice/main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/login", loginHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
}

func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    uuid := r.URL.Query().Get("user_id")
    w.Write([]byte(uuid))
}
```

Comment: This also solved my other two questions too. I have missed request/response cycle. I will update that question later.